# scrbook page numbers margin problem

Tags: margins, koma-script, scrbook

I was looking for the setting to adjust the vertical margin of the page numbers in the `scrbook` class but haven't found anything. I want to have them "nearer" to the page margin.

```
\documentclass[oneside,ngerman]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: KOMA doesn't provide such a feature. For special settings you should use the package `geometry` which is recommend in the documentation. You should use the option `reset` of the package geometry to set the original margins of KOMA.

Comment: Thank you very much, the following code achieves what I want (I've changed the original post as I cannot seem to post code in comments). However, what is the default margin?

Comment: Use the option `reset`.

Comment: Your set screw to influence the type area is the `DIV` option for the document class. `DIV=12` seems to work fine here. Other settings for the »typearea« package are described in the [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) user guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(OP's answer, moved from question)

Edit: The following code does the trick (following Marco's advise). Change 10em to whatever you want.

```
\usepackage[bottom=10em]{geometry}
```

Answer (score 1):

With package `scrlayer-scrpage` you can set or shift only the footer position modifing the foot layers of `scrheadings` and `plain.scrheadings`:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}[2015/07/02]
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{scrheadings}{%
  \ifstrstart{#1}{scrheadings.foot.}{\ModifyLayer[align=b,voffset=\dimexpr\paperheight-2cm\relax]{#1}}{}%
}
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{plain.scrheadings}{%
  \ifstrstart{#1}{plain.scrheadings.foot.}{\ModifyLayer[align=b,voffset=\dimexpr\paperheight-2cm\relax]{#1}}{}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]